# Restart application on unhandled exception

Tags: c++, windows, exception

Is it possible to have a program restart automatically if it crashes?

Something like:

1. An unhandled exception is thrown.
2. Release all resources allocated by process.
3. Start over and call main.

I would like this behavior for a server application I'm working on. If clients miss use the server it can get a std::bac_alloc exception, in which case I would like the server to simply restart instead of crashing and shutting down, thus avoiding manual startup.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to *fix* the server?

Comment: @forsvarir - Yup. You don't always have the ability to do that though. For example, I used to do something very much like this for the SETI@Home client back in its early days, as it would occasionally die for no apparent reason. If I'd gone on vacation or something, I might not notice for a while, which would cause me to fall horribly behind my co-workers. Can't have that!

Comment: @T.E.D.: A good point and to be honest, I've used shell scripts in the past to do a similar thing (as a safety net).  But in this case, it felt like there was perhaps an idea what the problem was... but it's late and maybe I'm reading too much into it :)

Comment: @forsvarir, I had a similar situation with a process that I didn't write or have the source to. I got annoyed with the 2AM phone calls when it crashed, so I finally wrote a monitoring program that just restarted the process after it disappeared. Not a perfect outcome, but I slept a lot better!

Comment: @forsavir: Ofc. But it will be difficult to make it 100% problem free.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've done this before in Windows by running said program from another program via a win32 [CreateProcess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682425%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) call. The other program then waits on the "monitored" process to exit, and calls its `CreateProcess()` again if it does. You wait for a process to exit by performing a [WaitForSingleObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa450988.aspx) on the process' handle, which you get as one of the return values from your `CreateProcess()` call.

You will of course want to program in some way to make the monitoring process shut itself and its child process down.

Comment: loosely known as a "watchdog" process..and it's a pretty common pattern on *nix. If you write your application as a windows service, I'm pretty sure you can configure the service manager to restart your process for you. Then you need good logging (And crash dump handling) to help diagnose the source of the issue.

Comment: If your service really crashes and dies, Windows can restart it automatically. But if it doesn´t (just hangs, for example), Windows does nothing.

Comment: "some way to make the monitoring process shut itself and its child process down." don't stop there :).

Comment: @ronag - Well, I stopped because it depends greatly on how your monitoring process is written and what else you want it to do. For instance, as an MFC program you could put that code in an OnExit callback. As a background process, you might need to write a special "shutdown" program that twiddles an event object or something. If you write it as a Windows Service, you can hook onto the service stop event.

Answer (score 4):

Let Windows be your watchdog. You can call [`ChangeServiceConfig2`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681988.aspx) to set the *failure actions* for your service. (If your server isn't a service, then you're doing it wrong.) Specify `SERVICE_CONFIG_FAILURE_ACTIONS` for the `dwInfoLevel` parameter, and in the [`SERVICE_FAILURE_ACTIONS`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms685939.aspx) structure, set `lpsaActions` to an array of one or more [`SC_ACTION`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms685126.aspx) values. The type you want is `SC_ACTION_RESTART`.

Answer (score 3):

I did something similar by implementing a watchdog. The watchdog ran as a service and would wait for a ping (called petting the dog) from the monitored process. If the monitored process died due to an exception, watchdog would cleanup and relaunch the application.

In case the application was not responding(no ping in a certain time) the watchdog would kill it and then restart it.

Here is a link to an implementation that you might want to use:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/security/WatchDog.aspx

(PS: I implemented my own version but I cannot post it here. I found this from a quick google search and have no first hand experience with this particular implementation.)

Answer (score 1):

If you just catch the exception, it should be possible to just restart your server by internal programming logic without completely restarting the whole program.

Comment: It´s the right procedure if you know all the exceptions that the application can throw.

Comment: You can also just catch any exception.

Comment: A catch(...) {} clause should be able to fix that.  Static variables could be a bother, though.

Comment: This won't clean up the mess that caused the exception in the first place. Better to exit completely and start from scratch.

Comment: Ok, I suppose a std::bad_alloc means you really are in a bad situation.

Answer (score 1):

Like @T.E.D., we've done this in an application we built. Our application is a windows service, so the helper program stops the service (eventually kill it, if it hangs) and start the service again.

Comment: Yeah, a service was invloved in my case as well. Anyone who isn't afraid of a little Ada can look over the sources at http://www.telepath.com/~dennison/Ted/SETI/SETI_Service.html

Comment: Nice! I´ve used the SETI@Home screensaver for some time, but unfortunately haven´t found any little green men :-)